# How to validate username and password using ASP.NET and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write an asp.net code in C# which will basically have a login page with username and pass. If I enter username and pass as "admin" it will open the `Admin.aspx`.

Likewise for "employee" it's `employee.aspx` and for "manager" it's `manager.aspx`.

I have written quite a bit but stuck at the end.. please help how to open the appropriate page.. The username and password are stored in a database and I have to match it with the database

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=payroll;Integrated Security=True");
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select employeeid FROM employees WHERE username='" + TextBox1.Text + "'and password='"+TextBox2.Text+"'", con);

     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);

     con.Open();

     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     if (dr.Read())                         //I'M WRONG FROM HERE ONWARDS.
     {
        Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx"); 
     }

     con.Close();
     dr.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should:

- **REALLY** use **parametrized** query to avoid SQL injection and other messy business
- put all your disposable objects like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(...) { ... }` blocks
- read both the `employeeid` **and** the `role` of the employee to make the decision where to jump off to
- avoid using `AddWithValue` which has its drawbacks (see )
- ALSO: you should **NOT** store your passwords in **CLEAR TEXT** in your table! You should **ALWAYS** hash & salt your password - no exception

Try this code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // define your connection string (typically from a .config file) and your query WITH parameters!
    string connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=payroll;Integrated Security=True";
    string query = "SELECT employeeid, role FROM employees WHERE username=@user AND and password=@pwd;";

    // set up a connection and command in using() blocks
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        // add parameters and set their values
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pwd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text;

        // open connection
        con.Open();

        // establish data reader
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // if at least one row is returned....  
            if (dr.Read()) 
            {  
                // get employee ID and role from the reader
                string employeeId = dr.GetFieldValue<string>(0);
                string role = dr.GetFieldValue<string>(1);

                // depending on role, jump off to various pages
                switch (role)
                {
                    case "admin":
                       Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx"); 
                       break;

                    case "manager":
                       Response.Redirect("manager.aspx"); 
                       break;

                    default:
                       Response.Redirect("employee.aspx"); 
                       break;
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                   // what do you want to do if NO ROW was returned? E.g. user/pwd combo is wrong
                }

            dr.Close();
        }    

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need one extra thing and that is `dropdown list` and that dropdown will be used to specify user type.

Or better would be if you have separate page for each login type.

Comment: yes I can do with the dropdown menu..I was trying this so it would do it automatically.....

Comment: then just do what u are doing. and when you authenticate against db, at that time also get role and based on that redirect to respective page

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dr.Read()){                         
  if(dr.HasRow()){
    if(dr["username"].ToLower() == "admin"){ 
        Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
    }else if (dr["username"].ToLower() == "manager") {
        Response.Redirect("manager.asp");
    }//and more else if   
  }                                                

}
```

Comment: okay trying this..just a question though..with your code- if(dr["username"].ToLower() == "admin") it is only checking the username...do i have to do the password check here by using && dr["password"] ? or it will be done by the query itself?

Comment: Hm, you should check `dr.HasRow()` just before `If`s. If it returns true means username and password combination is true.

Comment: okay..so do i need the  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
??